# MVC / javascript race condition?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, race-condition

I am creating an mvc app.
I use sessionStorage to keep track of the database dirty state.

In the Nav Bar menu I have this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Monthly Service", "SideBySide", "TubShop", new { onclick = "SaveAlert(event);" })</li>
```

When the user clicks this link, I need to quick check to see if the dirty bit is set, warn the user to save first, and do nothing.

If the SaveAlert function looks like this it works albeit unconditionaly.

```
function SaveAlert(e)
{
   alert("Save your work");
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

However, if I dare check the dirty bit the new page loads and there is no Alert shown. Debugging this shows sessionState["DbDirty2"] to indeed be true. This is set "long ago" whenever the user makes a change to the table they are working on.

```
function SaveAlert(e)
{
   if(sessionState["DbDirty2"] == true)
   {
        alert("Save your work");
        e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

As a test I tried this and this "worked" but unconditionaly.

```
function SaveAlert(e)
{
   if(true)
   {
        alert("Save your work");
        e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

I have tried extracting "DbDirty2" to a Razor variable and sending it over as a second argument along with the event but DbDirty was stale as it was extracted at page load time not way later when the user clicks the link.

is there a better way?

Comment: Is `sessionState["DbDirty2"]` set to `'true'` or `true`? Since `'true' == true` is `false`.

Comment: @Sani Singh Huttunen. Thank you!!! it was "true" in the watch list. I payed no attention to the quotes smugly knowing I stuffed a boolean in there. sessionStorage["DbDirty2"] = true; Yet it was indeed a string. - Stupid sessionState. And stupid Ron. Thank you. That's a weekend I won't get back. :-)